# Parsing program output line by line on-the-fly

Tags: linux, shell, parsing, stdout

I have a program that does some heavy processing (ML algorithm) and writes lots (read GBs of plain text) of data to standard output. In some particular scenarios, I only require a tiny portion of the output, however right now I am saving a (huge) text file and then parsing the lines in there to get my data.

While totally effective my approach is awfully efficient. Is there a way to avoid the generation of such big files (since most of the data will be removed anyway), and do the parsing on-the-fly line by line.

Execute:

```
./myProgram model test > myOutput
```

myOutput content (millions of lines):

```
0, blah blah blah thousand of more blahs -> [ I care data inside brackets ]
0, blah blah blah thousand of more blahs -> [ I care data inside brackets ]
....
```

What I think could be the best option would be to use the unix pipeline to chain results but I do not know how to send the data line by line lets say to a python or java app to parse it.

```
./myProgram model test | <now what>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read and write data in the script you want to use to filter the data just read and write from/to standard input/output.

```
./myProgram model test | ./filter.py > myOutput
```

filter.py:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    if some_condition:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

If the condition is just to have some pattern in the data you don't need a script, you can simply use `grep` to filter the lines:

```
 ./myProgram model test | grep 'interesting_pattern' > myOutput
```

Answer (score 1):

That pipeline does exactly that. It sends the data (possibly buffered) to the program on the RHS of the pipeline.

That program can then operate on that data in any way it wants.

Programs like `grep`, `sed` and `awk` operate on that data in line-oriented fashion.

Other programs can do other things as they want/need to.

Answer (score 0):

> ./myProgram model test | now what

If I understand correctly that you want `[ I care data inside brackets ]` (just the data between the brackets), then one proper approach is to pipe the output to `sed` and then using a `backreference` to replace the line of text with just what is inside the brackets. So `now what` is `sed -e 's/^.*[[]\(.*\)[]].*$/\1/'`. Or put together:

```
./myProgram model test | sed -e 's/^.*[[]\(.*\)[]].*$/\1/' > myOutput
```

If your program provides the output provided, an example is:

```
$ echo "0, blah blah blah thousand of more blahs -> [ I care data inside brackets ]" | 
sed -e 's/^.*[[]\(.*\)[]].*$/\1/'
 I care data inside brackets
```

A brief explanation of the regular expression is relatively easy if you look at it in pieces:

```
 's/^.*[[]\(.*\)[]].*$/\1/'
```

Is a simple substitution expression of the form `s/this/that/`. Looking at the first (or `this`) part you have:

```
^.*   # from the beginning of the line, match all characters
[[]   # until you find the first open bracket [
\(    # begin saving the pattern that follows
.*    # all characters in this case
\)    # stop collecting the pattern
[]]   # before you encounter the close bracket ]
.*$   # and then all remaining characters in the line.
```

Next the second (or `that`) part of the `s/this/that/` expression is a `backreference` that says:

```
\1    # substitute the (1st) pattern you collected. All between \(...\) for the line.
```

Which when put together simply says **replace the line with just what is between the brackets.** (and of course if I didn't understand what you needed, it's a long explanation down the tubes.)

Answer (score -1):

If indeed the output is line oriented and you want to extract or process some of it, pipe the output to some `awk` command, i.e.

```
 ./myProgram model test | awk ...
```

of course, replace the `...` with appropriate arguments for `awk`. Learn more about [GNU awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) (a.k.a. `gawk`) it is designed for such tasks:

> If you are like many computer users, you would frequently like to make changes in various text files wherever certain patterns appear, or extract data from parts of certain lines while discarding the rest. To write a program to do this in a language such as C or Pascal is a time-consuming inconvenience that may take many lines of code. The job is easy with awk, especially the GNU implementation: gawk.

Alternatively, you could modify your original `./myProgram` to let it e.g. fill some database, either with [sqlite](http://sqlite.org) (an easy to use library) or with something more serious like [PostGreSQL](http://postgresql.org) or [MongoDb](http://mongodb.org/)